# Symfony mapping compiler pass

Tags: mapping, symfony-2.5

I'm using Symfony 2.5 freshly installed from the top of this page: http://symfony.com/download

I'm trying to register a mapping compiler pass following the instructions on this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html

Note the "2.5 version" marker on top of the page.

However, the file used in the sample code:

```
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass
```

does not exist in my install. Everything else is there.

Here's my composer.json:

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony" : "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions" : "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0"
},
"require-dev" : {
    "sensio/generator-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.2.*"
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening an [issue ticket](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/333) at the Doctrine Bundle repository. It turns out there was a small typo in the Symfony doc, which [has been fixed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/4273).